# How should I tokenize a string into char using boost

Tags: c++, string, boost, tokenize, boost-tokenizer

I am trying to tokenize a string into character using boost

The present boost tokenizer will tokenize  based on space

```cpp
 typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> >
    tokenizer;
  boost::char_separator<char> sep("");
  tokenizer tokens(str, sep);
```

I expect output to be
j
e
f 
but the the actual output is
jef

Answer (score 0):

This

```
""
```

is string literal with no characters ended by null terminator.
Whereas

```
" "
```

is string literal which contains one character - **space** also ended by null terminator.
If you want to split `str = "j e f"` by space you need to write something like this:

```
  typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> >
        tokenizer;
  boost::char_separator<char> sep(" ");
  std::string str = "j e f";
  tokenizer tokens(str, sep);
  for (auto i : tokens)
    cout << i << endl;
  // output
  j
  e
  f
```

As the name `char_separator` suggests it takes **characters**, your string `""` contains no chars. Splitting is realized by comparing separator character with input string. How do you want to do this comparison when there is no character to do it, i.e. `""`?

Comment: My input is "jef" and not "j e f", my input has no spaces

Comment: What is unclear in my answer? `""` as delimiter has no characters, so your input cannot be spliited. There is no character which doest the split. If you want to get `j`, `e` and `f` you can just iterate over "jef" and get each character.